# Efficiency of imports in Python

Tags: python

I have a module with many functions:

**Module One**

```
def a():
 ...
def b():
 ...
def c():
 ....
```

Now, from a different module, I need to import only function b. For that purpose, i am using the syntax:

```
from One import b
```

**My question** - beside from namespace considerations, is there any positive effect on the time complexity of my program if I use the import stated above rather than `import One` , since that way I only import the necessary functions (for the sake of the example I only used 3 function in `module One`, but I have many more)

Comment: 1.  An import never has any impact on "complexity".  I think you're using the phrase "time complexity" incorrectly.  If you're asking about "run time", there may be a microscopic impact.  2.  Don't optimize your imports, strive for clarity and meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's find out by benchmarking. Start with the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in xrange(100000):
    print "def foo%d(): pass\n" % i
```

Which generates a large Python program. We save it to `foo.py`.

Program `import.py` just does a `import foo`, (four repeats):

```
# time python import.py

7.83s user 0.55s system 99% cpu 8.381 total
1.52s user 0.11s system 99% cpu 1.630 total
1.54s user 0.09s system 100% cpu 1.626 total
1.48s user 0.15s system 100% cpu 1.623 total
```

The second (and subsequent) executions are faster, because Python creases a file `foo.pyc` after importing `foo` the first time, which contains the results of parsing `foo.py`. This speeds up all subsequent imports of the module.

Program `fromimport.py` does a `from foo import foo1`, (four repeats):

```
# time python fromimport.py

7.81s user 0.44s system 99% cpu 8.253 total
1.48s user 0.15s system 100% cpu 1.626 total
1.52s user 0.11s system 99% cpu 1.631 total
1.49s user 0.14s system 100% cpu 1.630 total
```

These times are very similar to the previous program (once again, the first time being slower because Python needs to parse the `foo.py`), which confirms the statements of other answers already provided that there is no significant performance difference between `import foo` and `from foo import foo1` in common scenarios.

As others have noted, this is because Python needs to parse/run the entire file, even if only a small part of it is actually used by the caller.

Answer (score 6):

No. The full module must be completely run (the first time) to be certain that the name will even exist within it regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The full module has to be loaded, imagine this:

```
b = 1
def a():
    return b
```

Now in our second file:

```
from somemodule import a

print a()
```

uh oh

Comment: This doesn't address the timing the OP asked about.

Comment: I think envalid is trying to give an example of why the full file needs to be parsed by Python, even if you only want to import a small part of it.